# Replace duplicated values in consecutive runs with blank

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, grouping

First, some data:

```
library(data.table)

# 1. Input table
df_input <- data.table(
  x = c("x1", "x1", "x1", "x2", "x2"),
  y = c("y1", "y1", "y2", "y1", "y1"),
  z = c(1:5))
```

In each column, I want to keep only the first value in each run of consecutive values. E.g. look at the `y` column, which has three different runs: (1) two `y1`, (2) one `y2`, and (3) a second run of `y1`. Within each such run, duplicated values should be replaced with `""`.

```
#     x  y z
# 1: x1 y1 1   # 1st value in run of y1: keep
# 2: x1 y1 2   # 2nd value in run: replace
# 3: x1 y2 3   # 1st value in run: keep
# 4: x2 y1 4   # 1st value in 2nd run of y1: keep
# 5: x2 y1 5   # 2nd value: replace
```

Thus, the desired output table:

```
df_output <- data.table(
  x = c("x1", "", "",  "x2", ""),
  y = c("y1", "", "y2", "y1", ""),
  z = c(1:5))

#     x  y z
# 1: x1 y1 1
# 2:       2
# 3:    y2 3
# 4: x2 y1 4
# 5:       5
```

How it's possible to get "output" table by using dplyr or data.table packages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rleid` with `duplicated` to `replace` consecutive repeating values with empty value (`''`).

```
library(data.table)
df_input[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(rleid(x)), ''))]


#    x  y z
#1: x1 y1 1
#2:       2
#3:    y2 3
#4: x2 y1 4
#5:       5
```

Using it in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df_input %>% mutate_all(~replace(., duplicated(rleid(.)), ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `set` with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
for(j in names(df_input)) 
  set(df_input, i = which(duplicated(rleid(df_input[[j]]))), j = j, value = '')

df_input
#    x  y z
#1: x1 y1 1
#2:       2
#3:    y2 3
#4: x2 y1 4
#5:       5
```

Comment: i think `rleid` is not required